# Parsing a json object-array in python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file in following format:

```
{
"alpha":"12233321",
"beta":
      { 
       "beta1":12.2232,
       "beta2":23.4445
       },
"gamma":
      {
        "gamma1":23.12312,
        "gamma2":12.33445
       }
}
```

I want to store alpha in a variable, beta and gamma in a numpy arrays.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am actually clueless on how to start. Because i am confused as this json object contains a single variable and then sets of variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
import json
import numpy as np

with open("data.json", "r") as f: # data.json is your json file
    info = json.load(f)
    alpha = info["alpha"]
    beta = np.array(list(info["beta"].values())) # instantiate np array
    gamma = np.array(list(info["gamma"].values())) # instantiate np array

    print("Alpha:", alpha)
    print("Beta:", beta)
    print("Gamma:", gamma)
```

This prints:

```
Alpha: 12233321
Beta: [12.2232 23.4445]
Gamma: [23.12312 12.33445]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas to read the json

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_json('<json_file>')

beta_array = np.array(df[~df.beta.isnull()].beta)
gamma_array = np.array(df[~df.gamma.isnull()].gamma)
```

Comment: There is actually a module that could be used instead of pandas, `json`. Using `json.loads(string)` the output would be a `dict`.

Comment: @jcaliz ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding 'true'

Comment: @TomRobinson could you provide me an example on how will you work on this? also it is difficult to convert dicts to numpy ndarrays